# Adding instance/concurrent sessions in Selenium docker grid 4 is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I have configured the following yml file that spins up multiple instances of each node and all nodes booting correctly.

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-event-bus:
    image: selenium/event-bus:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210804
    container_name: selenium-event-bus
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "5557:5557"

  selenium-sessions:
    image: selenium/sessions:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210804
    container_name: selenium-sessions
    ports:
      - "5556:5556"
    depends_on:
      - selenium-event-bus
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-event-bus
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  selenium-session-queue:
    image: selenium/session-queue:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210804
    container_name: selenium-session-queue
    ports:
      - "5559:5559"
    depends_on:
      - selenium-event-bus
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-event-bus
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  selenium-distributor:
    image: selenium/distributor:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210804
    container_name: selenium-distributor
    ports:
      - "5553:5553"
    depends_on:
      - selenium-event-bus
      - selenium-sessions
      - selenium-session-queue
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-event-bus
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_SESSIONS_MAP_HOST=selenium-sessions
      - SE_SESSIONS_MAP_PORT=5556
      - SE_SESSION_QUEUE_HOST=selenium-session-queue
      - SE_SESSION_QUEUE_PORT=5559

  selenium-router:
    image: selenium/router:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210804
    container_name: selenium-router
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    depends_on:
      - selenium-distributor
      - selenium-sessions
      - selenium-session-queue
    environment:
      - SE_DISTRIBUTOR_HOST=selenium-distributor
      - SE_DISTRIBUTOR_PORT=5553
      - SE_SESSIONS_MAP_HOST=selenium-sessions
      - SE_SESSIONS_MAP_PORT=5556
      - SE_SESSION_QUEUE_HOST=selenium-session-queue
      - SE_SESSION_QUEUE_PORT=5559

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210804
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-event-bus
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-event-bus
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - NODE_MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSIONS=25
    ports:
      - "6900:5900"

  edge:
    image: selenium/node-edge:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210804
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-event-bus
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-event-bus
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - NODE_MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSIONS=15
    ports:
      - "6901:5900"

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210804
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-event-bus
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-event-bus
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - NODE_MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSIONS=50
    ports:
      - "6902:5900"
```

I would like to increase the concurrency by using this command `NODE_MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSIONS` but the Grid portal/UI is not reflecting and all tests are kept in the queue instead.

[image]

Any hints to make it parallel for running the tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently Selenium developers rework some stuff there and flags are the part of that reworks. The property you are using is not valid any more.

You need to use `SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS` in order to set up the number of concurrent sessions for your docker container. You would also probably need to set `SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true` because the default `false` value limits the maximum number of concurrent sessions to number of your cores.

Here I'm trying to keep the [up-to date guide to Selenium Grid 4 configuration properties](https://www.webelement.click/en/selenium_grid_4_complete_guide_to_configuration_flags).

Comment: Website link seems to be broken. Could you provide alternate link if possible

Comment: Just checked. Everything is working on my side: https://www.uptimia.com/website-availability-test/69ae2ac1